# Changing the color of a button when clicked based on the hash value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have three buttons the background color of the button should be changed when user clicks on it based on the hash value as I used routing concept here.

Here's what I have written 
HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="mainController">
  <ul class="list-group">
      <a ng-href="#/"><li class="list-group-item" ng-class="{'red': x=='#/'}" ng-click="showLocation()" >Home</li></a>
      <a ng-href="#/Second-page"><li class="list-group-item" ng-class="{'red': x=='#/Second-page'}" ng-click="showLocation()" >Second page</li></a>
      <a ng-href="#/Third-page"><li class="list-group-item" ng-class="{'red': x=='#/Third-page'}" ng-click="showLocation()" >Third page</li></a>
  </ul>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
          .list-group-item.red{
          background-color: red;
          color: white;
          padding: 10px;
      }
```

JS :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider

.when("/", {
   templateUrl: "main.html",
   controller: "mainController"
})
.when("/Second-page", {
    templateUrl: "Second.html",
    controller: "mainController"
})
.when("/Second-page/:num", {
    templateUrl: "Second.html",
    controller: "mainController"
})
.when("/Third-page", {
    templateUrl: "Third.html",
    controller: "secondController"
})
 .when("/Third-page/:num", {
    templateUrl: "Third.html",
    controller: "secondController"
})
```

});

```
myApp.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "serviceName", "$routeParams", "$location", function($scope, serviceName, $routeParams){
$scope.x = window.location.hash;
$scope.showLocation = function(){
   $scope.x = window.location.hash;
}
```

My problem is location.hash is not working properly. I'm getting previous hash value when clicked on the button.

For example, When I click on the first button nothing is happening, when I click on the second button first buttons hash value is taken and the first button is getting clicked. Now when I click on the third button, previous hash value which is second button's hash is taken and the second button is getting highlighted.

Css is getting applied to the previous hash value.

Can anyone clarify this for me, I'm really confused of what's happening exactly.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is probably a timing issue. try wrapping your `showLocation` login in a 0 length `$timeout` ie.  `$timeout(function(){ $scope.x = window.location.hash; })`

Comment: Got $timeout is not defined error @haxxxton

Comment: you need to inject `$timeout` just like you have done for `$scope`

Comment: Awesome it is working. Thank you so much, I've been working on it for a long time, couldn't find the mistake. Thank you @haxxxton :)

Comment: submitted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular sometimes works "too quickly" for some changes to be "heard" by the rest of your code.

In order to combat this you can add a 0 length `$timeout` to your code such that it waits until the next digest cycle to execute.

```
myApp.controller("mainController", ["$scope", "serviceName", "$routeParams", "$location", "$timeout", function($scope, serviceName, $routeParams, $location, $timeout){
    $scope.x = window.location.hash;
    $scope.showLocation = function(){
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.x = window.location.hash;
        });
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

To change the color of the button when it's been clicked is done by editing its css file.

```css
 .list-group-item.red{
          background-color: red;
          padding: 10px;
      }
      
 .list-group-item.red a{
          color: white;
       }

.list-group-item.red a:active{
          color: #fff;
          /*you can add any value after color:*/
       }
```

Comment: Even I know this process, but I thought of changing the color by using angular js and which should also be done by using the hash value. I have mentioned my requirement in the question clearly.